# How to group Widgets in my Qt app?

Tags: user-interface, qt, layout, widget

Easy question (I hope!). This is my first Qt app and I'm struggling with how to have groups of elements on my Gui.

I need about 8 standard QWidgets (labels, edits, buttons) for each File object, which can be added or removed dynamically.

So ultimately I need to put all the File objects inside a QVBoxLayout inside a QScrollArea.

But first I need to group them somehow. I realize I could draw them all on my main window with a lot of offsets, but it wouldn't be very elegant.

How can I make my File object extend *some sort of canvas* and each one maintains it's own set of widgets?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 5):

A `QWidget` can have a Layout and contain other widgets. So you could subclass `QWidget`, add whatever you need (along with a Layout) and use that wherever you want. Or even better (I think, based on your needs) is to subclass `QScrollArea` directly, add what you need including the layout, and then you can drop it in wholesale:

```
class MyWidget : public QScrollArea
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyWidget(const QString& filename, QWidget* parent = 0);
};

MyWidget::MyWidget(const QString& filename, QWidget* parent) : QScrollArea(parent)
{
    setWidgetResizable(true);

    QWidget* central = new QWidget(this);
    setWidget(central);

    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(central);
    central->setLayout(layout);

    layout->addWidget(new QLabel(filename, central));
    layout->addWidget(new QLineEdit("editor 1", central));
    layout->addWidget(new QLineEdit("editor 2", central));
    layout->addWidget(new QLineEdit("editor 3", central));
    layout->addWidget(new QLineEdit("editor 4", central));
    layout->addWidget(new QLineEdit("editor 5", central));
    layout->addStretch();
}
```

Then to use it:

```
MyWidget* widget1 = new MyWidget("/file1", parent);
MyWidget* widget2 = new MyWidget("/file2", parent);
layout->addWidget(widget1);
layout->addWidget(widget2);
```

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly what I was trying to do, but I adapted this. I made a FilePanel class extending QScrollBar and then I add FileItems to it dynamically. FileItems have Layouts with Widgets in them, so I add that Layout to (layout) held by (central). Only problem now is it doesn't draw anything when I add one after it's already initialized.

Comment: OK I got it working now, thanks! Yes it's interesting how you can nest widgets in layouts in layouts in layounts in widgets in layouts, etc. :)